# Date is this week, this month, this year

Tags: .net, datetime

I have `DateTime` value and I want to determine is this date on:

- Current week
- Current month
- Current year

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Calendar class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.globalization.calendar%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) of the .NET framework.

```
public static bool IsCurrentWeek(this DateTime dt)
{
    var f = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    var c = f.Calendar;
    var givenWeek = c.GetWeekOfYear(dt, f.CalendarWeekRule, f.FirstDayOfWeek);
    var givenYear = c.GetYear(dt);
    var thisWeek = c.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, f.CalendarWeekRule, f.FirstDayOfWeek);
    var thisYear = c.GetYear(DateTime.Now);
    return thisWeek == givenWeek && thisYear == givenYear;
}

public static bool IsCurrentMonth(this DateTime dt)
{
    return DateTime.Now.Month == dt.Month && dt.IsCurrentYear();
}

public static bool IsCurrentYear(this DateTime dt)
{
    return DateTime.Now.Year == dt.Year;
}

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
bool isCurrentYear = dateTime.IsCurrentYear()
```

Comment: Excellent answer, but I'd amend it a small bit to also check the year in the IsCurrentWeek() function. Otherwise you could have a date in say 1975, saying it is this week for a date in 2012. Outlined in answer below

Answer (score 3):

The month and year are easy:

```
if (yourDate.Month = DateTime.Now.Month)
    ...

if (yourDate.Year = DateTime.Now.Year)
    ...
```

Week is harder, since week rules differ per region.  Here's an example:

```
var dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
var cal = dfi.Calendar;

if (cal.GetWeekOfYear(yourDate, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, dfi.FirstDayOfWeek) ==
    cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, dfi.FirstDayOfWeek))
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Month` property on the `DateTime` type is an integer value between 1 and 12, so if you are looking to see if the date exists in the current month *of the current year* you are going to have to test against both properties:

```
if (yourDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && yourDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
    ...
```

Comment: +1 Good point, if you compare the month, you probably should also compare the year.

Answer (score 1):

This is just meant to expand on the comment to the accepted answer above:

(Date is a property set in the ctor)

```
    public bool IsThisWeek() 
    { 
        DateTimeFormatInfo dateTimeFormatInfo = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
        Calendar calendar = dateTimeFormatInfo.Calendar;

        // Get current week and year
        int thisWeek = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, dateTimeFormatInfo.CalendarWeekRule, dateTimeFormatInfo.FirstDayOfWeek);
        int thisYear = calendar.GetYear(DateTime.Now);

        // Get the week and year from the date
        int weekToCheck = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(this.Date, dateTimeFormatInfo.CalendarWeekRule, dateTimeFormatInfo.FirstDayOfWeek);
        int yearToCheck = calendar.GetYear(this.Date);

        return  ((thisWeek == weekToCheck) && (thisYear == yearToCheck)); 
    }
```